# Need to reference another table but must not be the same value as a column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

So I have the table funtom_timesheet with a coloumn called Timesheet_approved and I need to reference the table funtom_employee(emp ID),
the column timesheet_approved also must not be the same value as the column timesheet_emp, this is the code I have so far...

```
create table Funtom_timesheet 
(
timesheet_ID          number(3) constraint timesheet_pk primary key,
timesheet_Emp         number(3) constraint timesheet_Emp not null constraint timesheet_Emp references funtom_employee,
timesheet_Wc          date      constraint timesheet_Wc not null,  
timesheet_OT          number(2) default 0,
timesheet_Approved    number(3)  constraint timesheet_approved references funtom_employee constraint timesheet_approved unique(timesheet_Approved,timesheet_Emp) 
)
;
```

New code still errors...

```
create table Funtom_timesheet 
(
    timesheet_ID          number(3) constraint timesheet_pk primary key,
    timesheet_Emp         number(3) constraint timesheet_Emp not null references funtom_employee(emp_ID),
    timesheet_Wc          date      constraint timesheet_Wc not null,  
    timesheet_hours   number(2),
    timesheet_OT          number(2) default 0,
    timesheet_Approved    number(3),
    constraint timesheet_approved_uc unique(timesheet_Approved,timesheet_Emp),
    constraint timesheet_approved references funtom_employee(emp_ID)

);
```

Comment: This has some of the same fundamental errors as your last question. You seem to be inventing syntax rather than [following the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm). I suggest you try to apply the things said there to this table and then see where you are.

Comment: created this but still errors?  create table Funtom_timesheet (
    timesheet_ID          number(3) constraint timesheet_pk primary key,
    timesheet_Emp         number(3) constraint timesheet_Emp not null references funtom_employee(emp_ID),
    timesheet_Wc          date      constraint timesheet_Wc not null,  
    timesheet_hours   number(2),
    timesheet_OT          number(2) default 0,
    timesheet_Approved    number(3),
    constraint timesheet_approved_uc unique(timesheet_Approved,timesheet_Emp),
    constraint timesheet_approved references funtom_employee(emp_ID)

);

Comment: Looks like a job for a trigger - but I don't like to use them.

I'd ensure the UI only offers valid option to populate.

Comment: @TomMaughan - please edit your question to show that, it isn't easy to read as a comment. Thanks. It also helps to say *what* errors you get. The first two in-line constraints are still wrong though, same as the last question.

Comment: @AlexPoole done sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You're still making some of the same mistakes, and mixing the syntax for in-line and out-of-line constraints. The code you posted would get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis because the last constraint is malformed:

```
constraint timesheet_approved references funtom_employee(emp_ID)
```

should be specifying the constraint type and the column name in this table that it applies to:

```
constraint timesheet_approved foreign key (timesheet_Approved)
  references funtom_employee(emp_ID)
```

Your attempt at a unique constraint is wrong too; that would check a combination of `timesheet_approved` and `timesheet_em` can only appear in a single row in the table, *not* that the two column values in the same row are different. For that you need a check constraint:

```
create table funtom_timesheet (
  timesheet_id number(3),
  timesheet_emp number(3) not null,
  timesheet_wc date not null,
  timesheet_hours number(2),
  timesheet_ot number(2) default 0,
  timesheet_approved number(3),
  constraint timesheet_pk primary key (timesheet_id),
  constraint timesheet_fk1 foreign key (timesheet_emp)
    references funtom_employee(emp_id),
  constraint timesheet_fk2 foreign key (timesheet_approved)
    references funtom_employee(emp_id),
  constraint timesheet_check check (timesheet_approved != timesheet_emp)
);
```

The last line checks that `timesheet_approved` is not the same number as `timesheet_emp`, i.e. that someone hasn't approved their own timesheet. Both fields have FK constraints to valid employee records; the check constraints make sure those are different.

Comment: thanks very much will use this code as a syntax guide from now works fine.